# Express + Mongoose formatting response to send

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to javascript and not sure how exactly to format responses how I want.

Here is the code for my api:

```
router.get("/categories", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        Category.find()
        .then(documents => {
            res.status(200).json({
                documents
            })
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

I want to send the response as:

```
[
   {data},
   {data},
   {data}   
]
```

But this is how it's sending:

```
{
   documents: [
      {data},
      {data},
      {data}
   ]
}
```

How do I remove that outer layer in the response object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply don't create an object with a document key but pass it down directly

```js
router.get("/categories", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        Category.find()
        .then(documents => {
            res.status(200).json(documents)
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```